# обработка чекбоксов с записью в бд - PHP БД

Tags: php, база-данных

На странице есть форма для пользователя со списком видов работ (чекбоксы). Пользователь может выбрать одно или несколько значений.

Вопрос:

1. как обработать форму с записью в БД?
2. как правильно хранить в БД информацию, учитывая связь многим ко многим, а также с дальнейшей целью фильтрации по видам работ?

Есть три таблицы:

1. id пользователя и другая информация по нему
2. id видов работ и наименование видов работ
3. id пользователя и id видов работ

Как правильно записывать информацию о выбранных чекбоксах для определенного id-пользователя?

Comment: "Тетенька, дайте попить, а то так есть хочется, что аж переночевать негде". Вопрос надо задавать только один. Если интересует структура БД, то спрашивать надо про структуру. Если хочется, чтобы за тебя написали HTML форму, то надо спрашивать про HTML. Если хочется РНР код, то можно начинать быть скромнее в своих запросах, и учиться  делать что-то самостоятельно.

Comment: Спасибо,хоть за такой, но все же ответ) HTML у меня есть, PHP тоже напишу сама. Ограничу вопрос до структуры БД. Не могу понять как хранить правильно информацию с множественным выбором в БД. Буду благодарна за наводку.

Answer (score 1):

При отправке формы поля input[type=checkbox] отправляются в виде `name=value` в том случае, если они установлены. То есть если у нас есть

```
<form ...>
<input type="checkbox" name="service1" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="service2" value="1" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="service3" value="1" checked>
</form>
```

то при отправке такой формы (услуга 2 и услуга 3 включены) мы увидим на сервере что-то вроде

```
?...&service2=1&service3=1
```

Читать такие вещи можно конструкциями вида (это просто пример, не думайте, что он хороший)

```
$service1 = isset($_GET['service1']) && $_GET['service1'] ? 1 : 0;
$service2 = isset($_GET['service2']) && $_GET['service2'] ? 1 : 0;
$service3 = isset($_GET['service3']) && $_GET['service3'] ? 1 : 0;
```

Громоздко и довольно ужасно

Есть второй, более удобный на мой взгляд вариант представления нескольких опций:

```
<form ...>
<input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="service1">
<input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="service2" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="service3" checked>
</form>
```

Вместо service1 в значении поля флажка можно указать значение опции (например английское название, русское название, числовой код опции или номер артикула в каталоге)

На сервере такие вещи будут преобразованы сразу в массив значений:

```
$services = isset($_GET['service']) ? $_GET['service'] : array();
```

И вы можете работать с ним, как с массивом, через foreach и так далее

---

Второй вопрос касательно связи. Проще всего поступить через создание таблицы связей.

Если у вас есть сущность "пользователь" и у него может быть неизвестное количество "видов работ", то нужно организовать таблицу с полями "пользователь", "вид работ", "есть связь" (последнее поле не обязательно), можно просто создавать запись в таблице если связь есть, и не создавать - если ее нет

Работать с этим очень просто:

```
SELECT `service` FROM `links` WHERE `user_id` = N; /* Узнать виды работ для пользователя N */
SELECT `user_id` FROM `links` WHERE `service` = M; /* Узнать всех пользователей, для которых нужно выполнить работы M */
```

Однако будьте внимательны. Если "пользователь" заказывает работы регулярно, и может сделать заказ несколько раз с разным набором работ, то возможно нужна еще одна сущность - "заказ"

В этом случае "заказ" будет в отдельной таблице, он связан с пользователем  по `user_id` к примеру, а внутри "заказа" перечислены виды работ

Присмотритесь внимательнее к своей задаче, поймите ее, нарисуйте на листочке - что происходит и что может происходить, представьте себя на месте людей, который этим пользуются.. Словом - будьте программистом ) И все обязательно получится

Comment: Благодарю за развернутый ответ. сейчас у меня три таблицы: 1-ая: id и другие данные по пользователю, 2-ая: id_rabot и name_rabot (здесь перечислены виды работ) и 3-я: id и id_rabot. (связь 1 со 2). Это верно или нет?

Comment: @natasha111222 верно, только первое поле в третьей таблице надо назвать более явно. плюс использование транслитерации выглядит непрофессионально, лучше посмотреть в словаре перевод. Е примеру для работ подойдет слово tasksю то есть поля в третьей таблице лучше назвать id_user, id_task

Comment: @natasha111222, не привязывайтесь к таблицам. Это просто модель, как запись уравнения. Смотрите на реальную задачу и сосредоточьтесь на ней. Именно задача определяет какую модель нам выбрать, а не наоборот